# Помогите , не запускается Кривая Безье на экране

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stlib.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <math.h>

void bezier (int x[4],int  y[4])
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    ibt i;
    double t;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"c:\\tc\\bgi");
    for(t=0.0; t<1.0: t+=0.0005)
    {
         double xt=pow(1-t,3)*x[0]+3*t*pow(1-t,2)*x[1]+3*pow(t,2)*(1-t)
         double yt=pow(1-t,3)*y[0]+3*t*pow(1-t,2)*y[1]+3*pow(t,2)*(1-t)
         putpixel(xt,y,WHITE);
    }
    for(i=0; 1<4; i++)
        putpixel(x[i],y[i],YELLOW);
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return;

    void main()
    {
         int[x4],[y4];
         int  i;
         printf ("enter  x and y co-ordinates");
         for (i=0:i<4;i++)
             scanf("%d%d",&x[i],&y[i]);
         bezier(x,y);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как минимум в цикле `for(t=0.0;t<1.0:t+=0.0005) ` двоеточие надо заменить на точку с запятой и ниже в цикле `for (i=0:i<4;i++)` тоже. Кроме того, какая-то беда со операторными скобками и точками с запятой в конце строк

Comment: спасибо исправил

Comment: Пишет ,что файл не найден . Кто знает как решить?

Comment: вы просто открыли файл main33.cpp в редакторе? необходимо создать проект, туда этот файл добавить, потом скомпилировать...